# react-native navigation between screens

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am a beginner in react-native and I am to implement react stack navigation in my app. I am trying to make my App.js render my Home.js as the default screen. I was hoping to use the app.js as the home screen and add another Login screen but I couldn't . I can't make out what's wrong I am only getting the development server returned response error code: 500 . This is the code for App.js.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, KeyboardAvoidingView } from 'react-native';
import {createStackNavigator, createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation'

import Home from './Screens/Home';

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {screen: Home},
});

export default class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <AppNavigator />
    );
  }
}
```

This is my Home.js file.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, KeyboardAvoidingView } from 'react-native';
import {StackNavigator, createStackNavigator, createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation'


export default class Home extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Home',
  }

  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>This is the Home HomeScreen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are forgetting to create the App Container, take a look at this link https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/hello-react-navigation.html

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, KeyboardAvoidingView } from 'react-native';
import {createStackNavigator, createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation'

import Home from './Screens/Home';

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {screen: Home},
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

export default class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <AppContainer />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank You. I don't know if it works because all I am getting know is  Unable to resolve "../Screens/Home" from "App.js

Comment: that is because it cannot find the file in your directory if Screens dir is at the same level of App.js try removing the first dot "../Screens/Home"  => "./Screens/Home"

Comment: I just fxed it, I restarted expo again since I encounter dir issues sometimes. The navigation works just fine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I just fxed it, I restarted expo again since I encounter dir issues sometimes. The navigation works just fine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think, u have missed "createAppContainer". Try the code as follows.

```
const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Welcome: {
   screen: WelcomeScreen,
     }
 });

const AppNavigator = createAppContainer(AppStackNavigator);
```

And then use the AppNavigator in the render.